# Update Function in android SQLite is not working

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

In my application I need to add and edit data to the SQLite database. When I do update data function app do not give any errors but my database wont update. Here is my Update function. I search in the web for two days but couldn't make this. Please help me.

```
public long updateEvent(String id, String title, String description, String reminder, String alarm, Date date) {

    try {
        int rowid = Integer.parseInt(id);
        Log.i("com.eventmanager", "insert Event");
         formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
         String datestring = formatter.format(date);

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
        cv.put(KEY_REMINDER, reminder);
        cv.put(KEY_ALARM, alarm);
        cv.put(KEY_DATE, datestring);
        myDB.beginTransaction();

        Log.i("com.eventmanager","SQL UPDATE ");

        myDB.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowid, null);
        myDB.setTransactionSuccessful();

        myDB.endTransaction();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: just do `long i=myDB.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowid, null);` and print the `i` value in console. check and let us know what `i` print actually?

Comment: It gives 0; Is there any error in my code. I can't find it.

Comment: Maybe your transaction is causing this, try without them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be a problem in the update statement, Try:

```
 long i = myDB.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[]{rowid});

 if(i>0)
     return 1;  // 1 for successful
 else
     return 0;  // 0 for unsuccessful
```

And yes go through the [public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns 1; that's not ok... it should return ContentValues cv

```
return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID+"="+rowId, null)
```