# update is not working in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

HI all i have to update row in `SQLite`database table,i'm using update query for update row but it's not working also not throw any error.

**MY CODE:**

```
database.rawQuery(" UPDATE content SET  url2g = replace(url2g, '"
                + current_ip + "', '" + ip + "');", null);
```

please suggest me where i'm wrong.`Thanks`

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575211/android-sqlite-update-not-working) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119589/update-function-in-android-sqlite-is-not-working) link be helpful? I am sure many others have tackled this problem. If you can be more specific and perhaps provide some error log information, we can find an answer for you.

Comment: not any error code execute successfully

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i done this using following `execSQL`

```
database.execSQL("UPDATE content SET  url2g = replace(url2g, '"
                + current_ip + "', '" + ip + "');");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 public void updatemember(String id,String password,String status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ContentValues dataToInsert = new ContentValues();
        dataToInsert.put("status", status);
        dataToInsert.put("password", password);

        String where= " id = " + "\"" + id + "\"";

        try {

            db.update(TABLE_NAME, dataToInsert, where, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {


            String error = e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but i want to execute above sql statement for update row...any idea please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) says:

```
public void execSQL (String sql)
```

Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

So you need to use `execSQL()` for data modification like:

•INSERT
•UPDATE
•DELETE

```
rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)
```

Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.

The `rawQuery()`  should be used for `SELECT` purpose, it returns Cursor for SELECT queries.